# The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, fullpage.js

Hi i have a problem with adding more than 5 video to the fullpage.js

sometimes the video does not work and got this error `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()` in my chrome console.

and all the video not loaded in the network

[image]

i used data-autoplay from fullpage.js

This is how i called my video in html.

```
<div class="video__container">
   <video data-autoplay loop class="video"> 
      <source src="assets/Video_drone.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```

any solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A bit of code here would help a lot

Comment: Or at least a link with the reproduction of the issue? If you believe this is a bug in fullPage.js I would encourage you to open an topic in the [fullPage.js issues forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues) with an isolated reproduction and the step by step guide.

Comment: We issue a lot of play/pause commands to videos in our app and see this error often.

Answer (score 1):

This person wrote up a good overview:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted

Basically it looks the Promise returned from calls to play() needs to return before calls to pause() can be made.   Since you're using fullpage.js though, you may have to file a bug report or issue a patch with them, if their code is where the call to pause() is made.

I am a bit confused though as the spec here seems to define play() as returning void.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/embedded-content-0.html#the-video-element

And other places indicate no value is returned also:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_play.asp